# Javascript function will not work

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Everytime I run the script, it says:

> party is undefined

Here's what I got:

```
party()

var party = function (name){
    alert("You must find your way into the party and kill the VIP")
};
```

It won't run on any js website. What should I do?

Comment: While a human might be able to understand "Do the thing. The thing is to...", a computer is more logical than that. You must tell it "The thing is to... Now, do the thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either what @user148098 has suggested OR:

```
party()

function party(){
    alert("You must find your way into the party and kill the VIP")};
```

where you define a function explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

you must define your function before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You called party() before you defined it in var party = function (na...

Just define it first and than call it, like this:

```
var party = function (name) {alert("You must find your way into the party and kill the VIP")};
party()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you need to define a function before you call it. Here is an example:

```js
var party = function (name) {alert("You must find your way into the party and kill the VIP")};

party()
```

Additionally, you might not have embedded the script withing the proper tags to have it run. If I just put the preceding code into a file and save it as html it won't run because I haven't put it within the  tags. See below for exact code:

```html
<script>
 var party = function (name) {alert("You must find your way into the party and kill the VIP")};

    party()
 
</script>
```

Hope this helps!